# How to set number of lines in UIButton using UIButton.Configuration?

Tags: ios, configuration, uibutton

Before iOS 15 and new `UIButton.Configuration` setting number of lines of title label was as easy as

```
myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
```

I don't see any property in the `UIButton.Configuration` struct that would allow me to achieve this and the code above doesn't work when using configurations.

Comment: Infuriating to find this question without any answers when this is exactly the issue I'm struggling with. How is it possible apple did not foresee this basic issue?!

Comment: Looks like a `Button.Configuration.titleLineBreakMode` property is in beta. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/4130647-titlelinebreakmode :(

Comment: @Adam If you don't believe the linked duplicate solves your issue then please update your question with your attempted code clearly indicating exactly how the results do not meet your expectations.